# Getting Delegation to work with Cocoapod in Swift

Tags: delegates, swift, delegation

I'm working on a simple timer app. I have correctly set up my swift bridging header and declared the delegate protocol in my View Controller class
 `class SecondViewController: UIViewController, MZTimerLabelDelegate {`

Then, after `viewDidLoad()` I implemented the protocol for the Delegate:

```
func timerLabel(timerLabel: AnyObject!, finshedCountDownTimerWithTime countTime: NSTimeInterval){
  self.startTimer.setTitle("Ok!", forState: .Normal)
}
```

My instance of `MZTimerLabel` is called `brewTimer`. I'm not sure where to set `brewTimer.delegate = self`. I've also seen it done sometimes as `var delegate: myDelegate = //code here` which I don't understand at all. All the samples I can find of using delegation in Swift have to do with transitioning between two View Controllers which is not what I am trying to do.

I would like to click the Start button in my app and have the app change the label of a button when the timer is finished. My timer code that starts the timer is this:

```
else {
  brewTimer.start()
  buttonSelect = 1
  startTimer.setTitle("Reset", forState: .Normal)
  //Start the circle counter graphic
  circleCounterOuter.startWithSeconds(5)
  circleCounterInner.startWithSeconds(2)
  timerLabel(brewTimer, finshedCountDownTimerWithTime:5)
}
```

The last line in that function is where I call my delegate's protocol function, but when I click "Start" the label immediately changes to "OK!" instead of waiting for `finishedCountDownTimerWithTime`'s NSTimeInterval of 5. I'm working with the cocoapod MZTimerLabel if anyone is wondering.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out with input from a user on a different question. I read up on delegation from the [Apple link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html), but implementation was still confusing. The way I understand it, I had to tell my instance of MZTimerLabel to "delegate" at the point in code where I wanted the delegation to begin. I thouught this would happen automatically as long as I declared `brewTimer.delegate = self` *somewhere* in my View Did Load and that my delegation code would execute whenever my timer is run, but apparently this is not the case. Turns out I had to put `brewTimer.delegate = self` at the end of the function that told my timer to begin counting (my start button function):

```
else {
    brewTimer.start()
    buttonSelect = 1
    startTimer.setTitle("Reset", forState: .Normal)
    //Start the circle counter graphic
    circleCounterOuter.startWithSeconds(5)
    circleCounterInner.startWithSeconds(2)
    //set the delegate
    brewTimer.delegate = self
}
```

So the way I see it, the `brewTimer.delegate = self` statement tells my "special" delegate function to execute.

Comment: You should only have to assign the delegate in the `viewDidLoad`. The docs are wrong, the correct delegate is `func timerLabel(timerLabel: MZTimerLabel!, finshedCountDownTimerWithTime countTime: NSTimeInterval)`.